# How to Create a Uri without dontEscape Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

When I download page using HttpWebRequest, I have a problem:

Before create a new Uri, I escape the url, and pass it to Uri constructor. But when I use HttpWebRequest to download the page, it convert quote characterto '. Strange.

Orignal:

```
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_Julian_!_L'Élu_des_lémurs
```

Escaped, and pass to Uri constructor:

```
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_Julian_!_L%27%C3%89lu_des_l%C3%A9murs
```

HttpWebRequest send to server:

```
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_Julian_!_L'%C3%89lu_des_l%C3%A9murs
```

Below is my test codes:

```
private static void Test()
{
    var title = "Roi_Julian_!_L'Élu_des_lémurs";
    var url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + Uri.EscapeDataString(title);
    var uri = new Uri(url);

    HttpWebDownload(uri);
}

private static void HttpWebDownload(Uri uri)
{
    WebResponse response = null;
    StreamReader reader = null;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    response = request.GetResponse();
    reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    string pageResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine(pageResponse);
}
```

And this is trace log of system.net:

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [10640] WebRequest::Create(https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_Julian_!_L'Élu_des_lémurs)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [10640] HttpWebRequest#33111870::HttpWebRequest(https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_Julian_!_L'Élu_des_lémurs#-554901600)
System.Net Information: 0 : [10640] Current OS installation type is 'Server'.
System.Net Information: 0 : [10640] RAS supported: True
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [10640] Exiting HttpWebRequest#33111870::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [10640] Exiting WebRequest::Create()    -> HttpWebRequest#33111870
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [10640] HttpWebRequest#33111870::GetResponse()
System.Net Error: 0 : [10640] Can't retrieve proxy settings for Uri 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_Julian_!_L'Élu_des_lémurs'. Error code: 12180.
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [10640] ServicePoint#66337667::ServicePoint(fr.wikipedia.org:443)
System.Net Information: 0 : [10640] Associating HttpWebRequest#33111870 with ServicePoint#66337667
System.Net Information: 0 : [10640] Associating Connection#35489797 with HttpWebRequest#33111870
System.Net Information: 0 : [10640] Connection#35489797 - Created connection from 10.168.184.78:55975 to 198.35.26.96:443.
System.Net Information: 0 : [10640] TlsStream#45795543::.ctor(host=fr.wikipedia.org, #certs=0)
System.Net Information: 0 : [10640] Associating HttpWebRequest#33111870 with ConnectStream#65677972
System.Net Information: 0 : [10640] HttpWebRequest#33111870 - Request: GET /wiki/Roi_Julian_!_L'%C3%89lu_des_l%C3%A9murs HTTP/1.1

System.Net Information: 0 : [10640] ConnectStream#65677972 - Sending headers
{
Host: fr.wikipedia.org
Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
```

I thought this caused by the dontEscape parameter deprecated, so, I add a new function to fix it, but, I failed.

```
private const ulong UserEscape = 0x00080000;           
public static void EnableUserEscape(Uri uri)
{
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = uri.GetType().GetField("m_Flags", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (fieldInfo == null)
    {
        throw new MissingFieldException("'m_Flags' field not found");
    }
    var uriFlags = (ulong)fieldInfo.GetValue(uri);
    uriFlags = uriFlags | UserEscape;
    fieldInfo.SetValue(uri, uriFlags);
 }
```

Before pass Uri to HttpWebDownload(), I use this function to enable UserEscape, but finally HttpWebRequest send this kind of url(https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_Julian_!_L'?lu_des_l?murs) to server.

Anyone could give a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> in you test method define uri as below. may it will help you
>
> A string with @"somestring+SpecialCharacter" is called verbatim string . It basically means, "don't apply any interpretations to special characters inside the string until the next quote character is reached"

```
var url = @"https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_Julian_!_L'Élu_des_lémurs";
```

Comment: One more question, sometime I request a page, but server return a redirected url to me, how do you handle redirected url to create a new Uri, and continue to request page.

Comment: @GaryWang does previous one worked for you? if that is working kindly accept the answer

Comment: your answer does not work, var url = @"https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_Julian_!_L%27%C3%89lu_des_l%C3%A9murs" still will be converted to https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_Julian_!_L'%C3%89lu_des_l%C3%A9murs  in webrequest.